# In Views - If no revision is made then revision author shows the node author

Tags: views

I have a view with 2 columns. One shows the **Node Author** name and the other one shows **Node Revision Author** name. The problem is, when a new content is created with no revisions, the Node Revision Author Column shows the Node Author Name.

As per my expectation, if there are no revisions, then the Node Revision Author column should be empty. Is there any way to make this happen in views ?

Or

Is it possible to hide Author Name if **Node author = Revision Author** ?

Comment: There is always a current revision.

Comment: It's wired into the node module. You can change your view and do an aggregate count on the revisions for a node, and if it is only 1 then display nothing in the node revision author column.

Comment: I'll give it a try.